# Preventing a form from submitting when filled with new lines only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, forms

so I have a form that has a textarea and i don't want the form to be sent if the textarea is filled with just spaces or new lines `\n`, for the first condition i do

```
$("textarea").val().replace(/\u0020+/gm, ' ');
if($("textarea").val().length<2) return;
```

but i don't know how to prevent the form from submitting when the textarea is filled with new lines only.

Comment: Just so you know, a javascript (read client based) solution will not prevent someone from sending your server POST data with only new lines, to really validate this, you must perform the validation of data at the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### jQuery

I see that you're using jQuery. It has a handy [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function that will remove unnecessary whitespace in the beginning and end of the string. Running `trim` on a string that only consists of spaces, enters and other whitespace characters will result in an empty string - so it will work fine for you.

```
if($.trim($("textarea").val()).length < 2) return;
```

#### Javascript

Javascript also has a native [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) function, but old IEs don't support it. Using this code you can still "teach" them this method:

```
if(!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
  };
}
```

Comment: Isn't the point of `if (!String.prototype.trim)` to prevent the code from running in supporting browsers?